# Warning message with virtual event

Tags: c#

I want to use virtual event & override it in derive class. Following is the code snippet, I get a warning message while declaring the virtual event.

```
                using System;
                using System.Collections.Generic;
                using System.Linq;
                using System.Text;

                namespace ConsoleApplication6
                {
                    class Program
                    {
                        static void Main(string[] args)
                        {
                            DeriveClass obj = new DeriveClass();
                            obj.myEvent += new EventHandler(obj_myEvent);
                            obj.MyFunction();

                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }

                        static void obj_myEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Event fired.....");
                        }
                    }

                    public abstract class BaseClass
                    {
                        // I get warning on this line - Warning 1   The event 'ConsoleApplication6.BaseClass.myEvent' is never used Program.cs
                        public virtual event EventHandler myEvent;
                    }

                    public class DeriveClass : BaseClass
                    {
                        public override event EventHandler myEvent;

                        public void MyFunction()
                        {
                            if (myEvent != null)
                            {
                                myEvent(this, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Can anybody please tell me how to resolve this warning?

Atul Sureka

Comment: You can also declare an event on an interface and implement that interface.

Comment: @madd0 There can be many derive classes & set of events in base class. I want to override some of them in derive classes based on the requirement.

Comment: @AtulSureka I don't believe you need virtual events for that. I'd go with the answers suggested below.

Comment: You are getting that warning because you never use it.  If you use it then you wouldn't get the error.  If the code works then you can ignore the warning.  Of course this doesn't change the fact Ken's suggestion is better.

Comment: I do not want to do anything with that event in base class.         Following code resolved the warning public virtual event EventHandler myEvent = delegate { };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I do not want to do anything with that event in base class. Following resolved the warning.

```
  public virtual event EventHandler myEvent = delegate { };
```

Answer (score 3):

A more well-known pattern to use in this situation is to provide `DeriveClass` a protected method to raise `myEvent`. For example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    protected virtual void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e) {
        var local = MyEvent;
        if (local != null) local(this, e);
    }
}

public class DeriveClass : BaseClass {

    public void MyFunction() {

        OnMyEvent(null);
    }
}
```

This pattern will remove the warning. The warning exists because `myEvent` is never used in `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the event non virtual and implement a protected method that derived classes can use to raise it.  There really isn't any reason to have a virtual event.

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

protected void RaiseMyEvent()
{
    var myEvent = MyEvent;
    if (myEvent != null)
       MyEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: There can be many derive classes & set of events in base class. I want to override some of them in derive classes based on the requirement, I think virtual event is best suited for it

Comment: This resolve the warning         public virtual event EventHandler myEvent = delegate { };

Comment: You are resolving the error because you are forcing assignment to the variable, however, nothing in your code will ever actually activate that attached delegate.  I'm still not sure exactly what virtualizing the event accomplishes.  The type of the event is exactly the same, so all you have done is added some indirection.  If you remove all the virtual declarations and overrides from your code I believe you will not see a change in the behavior of your application.

Comment: After reviewing that post to see what you would use virtual events for, it appears that if you aren't actually calling the base version of the event your real issue is just that you should probably use abstract instead of virtual at the base level.